# Why is a point in a general distribution function always the probabiltiy 0?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $F_X(t)$ be an absolutely continuous general distribution function.

Why is $P(X=x) = 0$ always true?

(Our Professor stated this and did not explain anything about the context)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: If I pick a random number in $[0,1]$, what's the probablity I picked *exactly* $1/\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: If $X$ continuous with density $f$, then $$\mathbb P\{X\in A\}=\int_Af(u)\,\mathrm d u.$$ Therefore $$\mathbb P\{X=x\}=\int_{\{x\}}f(u)\,\mathrm d u=0.$$

Comment: As @Surb points out, this follows almost immediately from the definition of "absolutely continuous."  For intuition, the way I think of it is that since there infinitely many numbers in $[0,1]$, the probability of getting $1$ particular value if I draw one uniformly at random is $1/\infty = 0$.

Answer (score -1):

As the comments above have shown, this arises from the fact that any singleton event has measure $0$. Billingsley gives an intuitive explanation in his book `Probability and Measure`: consider $X \sim Uni[0, 1]$ which has a density with respect to Lebesgue measure, as you've required above.

Each value in the interval $[0, 1]$ can be represented as an infinite sequence of binary integers. For example, $0$ is $.00000...$, $0.1$ is $0.10000...$, and so on. Since $X$ is distributed uniformly over this interval, the digits of its binary representation are also uniformly distributed.

You can think of the binary representation as an infinite sequence of coin tosses, where heads gives $1$ and tails gives $0$. The probability of the event $\{X=x\}$ is equivalent to the probability of the corresponding infinite sequence of coin tosses exactly matching the infinite sequence defined by the binary representation of $x$. To me at least, it is intuitive that this probability is $0$.